# How to submit a form with KotlinJS and React?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I want to display a file selector and a submit button.
The file is only to be submitted once the button is clicked.
The submit/action target is on another server though.
I looked at react examples, but I can't figure out the exact method on how to
realise this with KotlinJS and React.

The duplicates in formMethod and onSubmitFunction are just me trying and seeing what sticks.
I also tried adding `method = FormMethod.post, encType = FormEncType.multipartFormData` directly to the form, but it didn't help. It doesn't even output the debug print.

EDIT: I do not need to do something with the file otherwise and want to leverage the default form functionality for the upload. The other server is also mine and has a simple html/http upload where this suffices:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

ENDEDIT

EDIT2: I changed the code a little and now it refers to the other server, but does not append any files.

```
private fun RBuilder.render() {
    form(
        method = FormMethod.post,
        encType = FormEncType.multipartFormData,
        action = "https://otherserver.com/upload"
    ) {
        styledInput {
            attrs {
                type = InputType.file
                accept = ".zip"
                multiple = false
           }
        }
        styledInput {
            attrs {
                type = InputType.submit
                value = "Test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in this case the name parameter is strictly required.

The following works:

```
private fun RBuilder.render() {
    form(
        method = FormMethod.post,
        encType = FormEncType.multipartFormData,
        action = "https://otherserver.com/upload"
    ) {
        styledInput {
            attrs {
                name = "upload"
                type = InputType.file
                accept = ".zip"
                multiple = false
           }
        }
        styledInput {
            attrs {
                type = InputType.submit
                value = "Test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```